# Tool for Converting from XPS to PDF format

Tags: pdf, xps

Does somebody knows about any tools for **converting from XPS to PDF format**?. I have some files in XPS but I need to convert them into PDF format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install [PDF Creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) and simply print your XPS file (or any file from any program that has printing capabilities) to PDF.

Comment: yes I know about PDF printers, but they convert HTML pages into PDF format, I need some tool that can read XPS and convert directly to PDF.

Comment: I don't see why PDF printer would do any worse job then any native program? Have you tried it ?

Comment: I have downloaded FreePDF, and it seem that the printed document is exactly as its XPS counterpart. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer PDF Creator myself. Use it at work on all computers. But as long as other programs do the job you're safe :-)

Comment: Beware the crapware that comes bundled with this software. A Toolbar and PDFArchitect which will shadily switch the default search engine of your browsers and who knows what else.

Answer (score 7):

GhostPDL ([sources](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/ghostpdl/), [binaries](http://code.google.com/p/ghostscript/downloads/list)), the sibling application to Ghostscript, can do that. It's a commandline tool. Which means you can also script it, and make the conversion non-interactivly. Printing to a "PDF printer" as was suggested above, does work as well of course. But it means you have to open the XPS in a viewer first, then click "print", select the PDF printer, etc. Interactively...

Here is a sample commandline to test the GhostPDL way:

```
gxps.exe ^
   -o output.pdf ^
   -sPDFSETTINGS=/prepress ^
   input.xps
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `xpstopdf`:

```
xpstopdf input.xps output.pdf
```

`xpstopdf` is part of `libgxps`, which can be installed by running `brew install libgxps` in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Acrobat 8 and later supports the direct conversion of XPS to PDF.  Just drop the file(s) onto Acrobat and it will produce PDFs for you.  No muss - no fuss!